# How do I replace a letter with another letter in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, invision-power-board

I am new here and please excuse me if I'm asking my question wrong or whatever.

I converted my old forum which was vbulletin to invision power board and I noticed that I have a turkish character problem in my forum:

```
ğ = ð
ı = ý
ş = þ
```

^They are looking like that and I need to fix this, unfortunately the support can't help me with this, since the issues was caused on vbulletin, so I have to fix it by myself and I thought I could just replace the wrong letters with the correct one, but ipb doesn't support such a function so I must do it in the db. So here is my question, is there a way to do it through phpmyadmin? Just replace the wrong letters with the right now?

Comment: are you using utf-8?

Comment: This post is extremely worthwhile reading, it will keep you out of 99% of similar problems now and in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/3536236

Comment: Also this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495008/is-there-a-way-to-convert-all-existing-table-data-to-utf8-collation

Answer (score 1):

Run this command on the individual tables

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE (column_name, 'Item to replace here', 'Replacement text here');
```

Comment: uhlmm, i don't follow, what do you mean?. But i've tried such and it worked for me.

Comment: sorry I got confused. it's ok, I read your code and thought you where changing the name of the column, but I realise that's well out. Lunch time.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but I am getting later this issue -> #1270 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'

Comment: okay, run this snippet then try again, `SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'` then for your database, `ALTER DATABASE db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` `ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following in MySQL using a [replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) in your query, you can change the characters providing you have the correct character set.

```
UPDATE table
SET colname = REPLACE(colname, 'ğ', 'ð')
WHERE ...
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but I am getting later this issue -> #1270 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'

Comment: Then you need to convert your db character set from swedish_ci to utf8. Follow Orions instructions from above. `ALTER DATABASE db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` and  `ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`